# JFileChooser: Preventing User from saving a file under existing name

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I am using a JFileChooser to save data from a textArea and I want to prevent the user from saving their new file under an existing name. Every time I execute the code, it only prompts the user one time to change the name of the file that they are trying to save. What way can I use the loop to keep the user from using an existing file name until they enter a new name? Here is what I have so far:

```
JButton OKSavebutton = new JButton("OK");
    OKSavebutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            final int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(fc, "Save new Observation Well File?", "Save File", 
                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File("C:/Users/281925/Desktop/mads/User Saved Internal Contamination Problem/Observation Wells"));

            FileNameExtensionFilter madsType = new FileNameExtensionFilter("MADS file (*.mads)", "mads");
            fc.setFileFilter(madsType);
            fc.addChoosableFileFilter(madsType);
            fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

        int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(fc);
        File f = new File(fc.getSelectedFile()+".mads");

            switch(result){
            case JOptionPane.OK_OPTION:
                if (f.exists()){
                    int result1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(fc, "The file name exists. Please input new File name", "New File Name", 
                            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                    fc.showSaveDialog(fc);
                }
                try{    
                    String fileExt = ".mads";
                        //create a buffered writer to write to a file
                        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fc.getSelectedFile().getPath() + fileExt));
                        out.write(textArea.getText());//write contents of the TextArea to the file
                        out.close();//close the file stream
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){  //catch any exceptions and write to the console
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }

                return;
            case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION:
                fc.cancelSelection();
                return;
                default:
                    return;
                    }

        }

    });
```

I have been on this for two days and I really need the help!! Please and thank you!

Here is the edited code. Thanks to @luk2302 for the assistance. I did have to tweak it a bit but now it works like a charm:)

```
int result1 = fc.showSaveDialog(fc);
        File f = new File(fc.getSelectedFile()+".mads");

        /* loop until the user entered a file that does not exist yet */
        while(f.exists()) { 

          result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(fc, "The file name exists. Please input new File name", "New File Name", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

          if(result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
             fc.showSaveDialog(fc);
         }
          /*Create new file and set it equal to f*/
          File f1 = new File(fc.getSelectedFile() + ".mads"); 
          f = f1;
        }

            /* return if user cancels */
        if(result == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) { 
            fc.cancelSelection();
            return;
          }
        /* if the user finally selected a non existing file do whatever needs to be done. */
        if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
          try { 
            String fileExt = ".mads";
            //create a buffered writer to write to a file
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fc.getSelectedFile().getPath() + fileExt));
            out.write(textArea.getText());//write contents of the TextArea to the file
            out.close();//close the file stream
            } catch(Exception e){  //catch any exceptions and write to the console
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
          return;
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do the following:

```
/* loop until the user entered a file that does not exist yet */
while(fc.getSelectedFile().exists()) { 
  result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(fc, "The file name exists. Please input new File name", "New File Name", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
  fc.showSaveDialog(fc);
  /* return if user cancels */
  if(result == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) { 
    fc.cancelSelection();
    return;
  }
}

/* if the user finally selected a non existing file do whatever needs to be done. */
if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
  try { 
    String fileExt = ".mads";
    //create a buffered writer to write to a file
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fc.getSelectedFile().getPath() + fileExt));
    out.write(textArea.getText());//write contents of the TextArea to the file
    out.close();//close the file stream
  } catch(Exception e){  //catch any exceptions and write to the console
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
  return;
}
```

Also note that you assign `int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(fc);` which is never used, instead you use in the rest of the code the value of `result`. So rename the variable to `` ` ``int result = fc.showSaveDialog(fc);`

Comment: Thanks for the assistance! I did have to tweak it a bit but now it does what I need it to do. Check out my revised code.

Comment: Nice of you to post the working code, glad you understood the general idea.

Comment: @B.Harper, There is no need to use a while loop and keep redisplaying the save dialog. I'm sure you get a lot of flicker when you use this approach.

Comment: @camickr why? `showConfirmDialog` as well as `showSaveDialog` "suspend" the program until the user acted in some kind of way, no flicker at all.

Comment: @luk2302, when I say flicker I mean the save dialog is hidden, the option pane displays, then the save dialog is displayed again. The cycle repeats. Normally the option pane appears above the save dialog and the save dialog is only closed once the user is finished selecting the filename.

Comment: @camickr Ah, okay, thats right and from a usability point of view not optimal, igree.

Comment: @luk2302 My apologies! The other day, I was checking this question and my computer was spazzing out for some strange reason. Didn't mean to un-accept it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just override the approveSelection method of JFileChooser

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser()
        {
            @Override
            public void approveSelection()
            {
                File f = getSelectedFile();
                if (f.exists() && getDialogType() == SAVE_DIALOG)
                {
                    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,
                                                               String.format("%s already exists.%n Overwrite?", f.getName()),
                                                               "File already exists", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

                    switch (result)
                    {
                        case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                            super.approveSelection();
                            return;
                        case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
                            return;
                        case JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION:
                            return;
                        case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION:
                            cancelSelection();
                            return;
                    }
                }
                super.approveSelection();
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the approveSelection() method to prevent/confirm this:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;

public class FileChooserSave
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser( new File(".") )
        {
            public void approveSelection()
            {
                if (getSelectedFile().exists())
                {
                    System.out.println("Do You Want to Overwrite File?");
                }
                else
                    super.approveSelection();
            }
        };

        chooser.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        });

        chooser.setSelectedFile( new File("something.rob") );
        int returnVal = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);


        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
           System.out.println(chooser.getSelectedFile() );
        }

    }
}
```